# angular 12 update: Module '"@angular/common"' has no exported member 'XhrFactory'

Tags: dependencies, node-modules, angular12

While running the angular application I am getting the error below:

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.d.ts:31:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@angular/common"' has no exported member 'XhrFactory'.

31 import { XhrFactory } from '@angular/common';
```

I have searched this error in the internet but didn't found a solution, to solve this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing      `import { XhrFactory } from '@angular/common';`
to

`import { XhrFactory } from '@angular/common/fesm5/http';`

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was different versions of `@angular/common` and `@angular/platform-browser`.

Problem was fixed when I upgraded `@angular/common` to latest version.